# Неправильное скалирование размера шрифта на мобильных устройствах

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема. 
Есть две страницы сайта: 1-ую делал я, вторую - мой коллега. 
Все общие стили писал я. 
Как итог - на моей странице, при сужении экрана, текст в заголовках неправильно скалируется и увеличивается, а на его странице всё в порядке. При этом, он ничего не дописывал и просто добавил свои селекторы в мои стили. 
Смотрел код в веб-инспекторе - всё одно и тоже написано.

Для наглядности:

[imgur.com/a/v3QfA](https://imgur.com/a/v3QfA) - моя страница,

[imgur.com/a/3deTH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLCdX.jpg) - его

Comment: Явно конфликт стилей происходит. "При сужении" - смотрите @media screen ... бывает одна мелочь, а влияет на многое.

Comment: Сайт не адаптивный

Comment: Хм, странности. Изменение размера шрифта при изменении размера экрана. И если шрифт не svg. Код бы показали.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/v3QfA - моя страница
http://imgur.com/a/3deTH - его

Comment: А код-то показать можете?